# Java Reflection Enumerate Type in GetMethod

Tags: java

I'm trying to call a method by name at runtime with reflection.
But I need to make this compatible with all methods.

I'll explain :

I have a text with this current format : `methodname|param1;param2;etc...`

Now i want this text split, and find the method in my class.

```
    try {
      String methodName = message.substring(0,message.indexOf("|"));
      method = ServerManager.class.getMethod(methodName, HERE I DONT KNOW WHAT TO PUT);

      //This code not tested yet//
      if(method != null)
      {
        method.invoke(ServerManager.class,message.split("|")[1].split(";"));
      }
    }
    catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

To find the method, I need to put the type. But number of parameters and the name of the method change. How can I give to `getMethod` an array of my parameters type ?

I've tryied to enumerate all `getClass()` of each parameters but `getMethod` seems not accepting array in second parameters.

Sorry for my bad english, and thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `class.getClass()` and then  you can pass an array of `Class`, for instance:

```
method = ServerManager.class
                      .getMethod(methodName, new Class[]{Integer.class, String.class});
```

or simply:

```
ServerManager.class.getMethod(methodName, Integer.class, String.class);
```

the array will be implicitly added there by Java compiler.